# C++ generate multiple random numbers without loop

Tags: c++, performance, loops, random

I want to generate 10000 random numbers from a normal distribution. Following lines gave me one number at a time. Is there a faster way to generate them? Maybe avoid looping?

```
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);
  double number[10000];
  for (int i =0; i< 10000; i++)
     number[i] = distribution(generator);
```

Comment: _"Maybe avoid looping?"_ There must be a loop somewhere, no?

Comment: Not sure. In Python or MATLAB, it can be done without loops.

Comment: The loops are probably going on in interned functions there, that create that data. Putting that loop in another function doesn't increase performance though.

Comment: You can hide loops... but doing stuff over and over is a loop...

Comment: Why do you think avoiding a loop will get it done faster? Even with the loop most of the time is the random generator itself anyway. If this particular generator is too slow for you, you need to use a different (faster) generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid explicitly writing a loop by using `std::generate_n`.

This is *extremely* unlikely to make any significant difference in speed though. Speed will be much more affected by the random number generator you use than by the code for the loop that invokes it.

I'd generally advise using `std::mt19937` over `std::default_random_engine`, but it's unlikely to give any massive increase in speed (but getting a good quality of random numbers generated becomes a lot more certain).